Teradata set role for a user is not working by c#
I am trying to build a console app that retrieves users from LDAP, creates the same users in Teradata, and grants privileges to these users based on their group membership.
My app is functioning well, but I have encountered an issue. When I assign a role to a user, the user must log in to Teradata and then manually execute SET ROLE ldapUser; once. I want to automate this process within my code so that the user does not have to log in and activate the role themselves.
Unfortunately, I have been unable to accomplish this task.
What I have done:
These are my codes for granting the privilege's and creating.
        string connectionString = "DataSource=123.123.123.123;Database=dbc;User ID=dbc;Password=dbc;SslMode=Disable";

        using (TdConnection connection = new TdConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection to Teradata established successfully");

                // Step 1: Create users for the ones not present in Teradata
                foreach (UserDetail userDetail in newDataToProcess)
                {
                    string checkUserExistsSQL = $"SELECT UserName FROM DBC.Users WHERE UserName = '{userDetail.Username}';";
                    using (TdCommand checkUserExistsCommand = new TdCommand(checkUserExistsSQL, connection))
                    {
                        object result = checkUserExistsCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (result == null || result == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            // User does not exist, create the user
                            string createUserSQL = $"CREATE USER {userDetail.Username} FROM dbc AS PERMANENT = 1000000, SPOOL = 1000000, TEMPORARY = 1000000, PROFILE = {userDetail.OU}, ACCOUNT = 'tauqer_account', PASSWORD = Mypassword;";
                            using (TdCommand createUserCommand = new TdCommand(createUserSQL, connection))
                            {
                                createUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                Console.WriteLine($"User '{userDetail.Username}' created successfully");

                                string grantLogonSQL = $"GRANT LOGON ON ALL TO {userDetail.Username} WITH NULL PASSWORD;";
                                using (TdCommand grantLogonCommand = new TdCommand(grantLogonSQL, connection))
                                {
                                    grantLogonCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }


                                 foreach (string cn in userDetail.CNs)
                                 {
                                     string grantRoleSQL = $"GRANT {cn} TO {userDetail.Username};";

                                    //string grantRoleSQL = $"GRANT {cn.Trim()} TO {userDetail.Username};"; // Trim to remove any leading/trailing spaces
                                    // using (TdCommand grantRoleCommand = new TdCommand(setRoleSQL, connection))
                                    using (TdCommand grantRoleCommand = new TdCommand(grantRoleSQL, connection))
                                     {
                                        grantRoleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        Console.WriteLine($"Granted role '{cn}' to user '{userDetail.Username}'");

                                        // grantRoleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        // Console.WriteLine($"User '{userDetail.Username}' granted the privilege '{cn.Trim()}'");
                                     }
                                    if (cn.Equals("LDAP_Admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        string setDefaultRoleSQL = $"GRANT {cn} TO {userDetail.Username} AS DEFAULT;";
                                        using (TdCommand setDefaultRoleCommand = new TdCommand(setDefaultRoleSQL, connection))
                                        {
                                            setDefaultRoleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            Console.WriteLine($"Set role '{cn}' as default for user '{userDetail.Username}'");
                                        }
                                    }
                                 }  
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"User '{userDetail.Username}' already exists in Teradata. Moving to the next user.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Step 2: Delete users from Teradata that are not present in newDataToProcess
                string selectExistingUsersSQL = "SELECT UserName FROM DBC.Users;";
                List<string> existingUsernames = new List<string>();
                using (TdCommand selectExistingUsersCommand = new TdCommand(selectExistingUsersSQL, connection))
                {
                    using (TdDataReader reader = selectExistingUsersCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string username = reader.GetString(0);
                            if (!newDataToProcess.Any(userDetail => userDetail.Username == username))
                            {
                                existingUsernames.Add(username);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (UserDetail existingUsername in uniqueInListLDAP)
                {
                    string checkProfileSQL = $"SELECT UserName FROM DBC.Users WHERE UserName = '{existingUsername}' AND ProfileName='TDLDAP';";
                    using (TdCommand checkProfileCommand = new TdCommand(checkProfileSQL, connection))
                    {
                        //object result = checkProfileCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                        // if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            string deleteUserSQL = $"DROP USER {existingUsername.Username};";
                            try
                            {
                                using (TdCommand deleteUserCommand = new TdCommand(deleteUserSQL, connection))
                                {
                                    deleteUserCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    Console.WriteLine($"User '{existingUsername.Username}' deleted successfully from Teradata.");
                                }
                            }
                            catch (TdException ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to delete user '{existingUsername}' from Teradata: {ex.Message}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (TdException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
I have tried every option I can think of, but no matter what, I have to log in once with the newly created user in order to set the role so the user can view authorized data. Can you please tell me how I can force that and set/activate the roles of the user using the dbc user?
It will be a great help.

Use the DEFAULT ROLE = clause in a CREATE USER or MODIFY USER SQL statement. You can either specify a rolename or the keyword ALL, which asserts the union of permissions for all granted roles. When a specific rolename is given, MODIFY USER requires that user has already been granted the role; CREATE USER will do the GRANT for you.

Not part of the answer, but several additional points worth mentioning: Don't use legacy DBC.Users, use DBC.UsersV instead. (In general when there are metadata views with and without the V suffix, you should always use the one with the V.) Also both DBC.Users and DBC.UsersV are filtered to return only those users on which the user running the query holds some permission or ownership. That's not a concern when querying as user DBC but can be important to know. Finally GRANT rolename AS DEFAULT is invalid syntax and will fail.

Thank you Fred, It work like a charm. Really appreciated. BTW, What If a user have more than one roles how can we manage this issue as more than one default roles are not allowed.

As Fred wrote: DEFAULT ROLE = ALL switches on all roles of a user
